# How to restrict webservice access to public user in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I have web service page(`webservice.asmx`) being consumed javascript call and I want to
restrict public request to this webservice other than request from local pages that is aspx or
from javscript. The web service checks for form-authentication before it gets executed but
list of services are viewable and the parameters are accesible in `.asmx` page . users can
type `www.site.com/webservice1.asmx` to access my webservice. so i need to restrict that
option. how do we secure the `asmx` file from public user access.?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to restrict HTTP GET access to your web service, modify the `webServices` section of Web.config:

```
<webServices>
     <protocols>
       <add name="HttpPost" />
       <remove name="HttpGet" />
       <remove name="Documentation"/>
     </protocols>
</webServices>
```

**Edit** - Other ways to disable HTTP GET

1. Add this attribute just above your web methods:

   ```
   [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
   ```
2. Add this check inside each web method:

   ```
   if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.POST)
       // Do your work
   ```

Comment: it is not working  ..I m  using forms authentication in application . Is there any security checking on service to restrict the public user.

Comment: it is working when i use <webServices>
<protocols>
       <remove name="Documentation"/>
</protocols>
</webServices> but i think it is  not a proper way ,                Is it possible to add security checking in webservice so that can restrict the users?